# Convert cURL request to Guzzle Request using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I haven't tried using cUrl Request with API and converting it to Guzzle HTTP.

I need to convert this cUrl to a working guzzle http post request to try the API

```
curl -X POST
"https://urltosendblahblah" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
{
    "outboundRewardRequest" : {
        "app_id" : "B54z9Ug55zLh5rTGRT5g6hq64pGUq6ap",
        "app_secret" : "f6554137d08f5607a696cd40741993758c411af3bb5f6c230270ec26e8d54126",
        "rewards_token" : "I7SkxKYid_F_p-JSgTejow",
        "address" : "9271051129",
        "promo" : "LOAD 50"
    }
}
```

Currently I had done this with my Guzzle Http but receiving 500 response

```
public function loadSample(){
    $url = "";

    $request = $this->client->post($url, [
        'verify'=>false,
        'outboundRewardRequest' => [
            'app_id'=>'',
            'app_secret'=> '',
            'rewards_token'=>'==',
            'address'=>'',
            'promo'=>''
        ]
    ]);
    $response = $request->getBody();
    dd($response);

}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$request = $this->client->post($url, [
    'headers' => [
        'verify' => false
    ],
    'form_params' => ['outboundRewardRequest' => [
        'app_id'=>'',
        'app_secret'=> '',
        'rewards_token'=>'==',
        'address'=>'',
        'promo'=>''
    ]],
      'debug' => false,
]);
```

Try this approach when using guzzle. Your body parameters must be a part of the `form_params` array.

Also you can set your guzzle debugging to false so you don't have any issues there.

Answer (score 1):

The expected key for the request body is `body` [source](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L114). So try changing `outboundRewardRequest` to `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your data in the `json` attribute or `form_params` depending on how it is received.

```
public function loadSample(){
    $url = "";

    $request = $this->client->post($url, [
        'verify'=>false,
        'json' => [
            'outboundRewardRequest' => [
                'app_id'=>'',
                'app_secret'=> '',
                'rewards_token'=>'==',
                'address'=>'',
                'promo'=>''
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $response = $request->getBody();
    dd($response);
}
```